# How to input command into python script

Tags: python

My current script is designed so that I am having to input 3 lines before I manage to open a certain website.

my code is named genius.py

I would like to know how to do it in one line 
e.g.

```
genius.py eminem lose yourself
```

My current code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import webbrowser

artist = raw_input("Enter artist name: ")
song = raw_input("Enter song name: ")

artist = artist.replace(" ", "-")
song = song.replace(" ", "-")

webbrowser.open("http://genius.com/"+artist+"-"+song+"-lyrics")
```

Comment: Are you looking for command line arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line arguments are in the `sys.argv` array.

```
import sys
artist = sys.argv[1]
song = sys.argv[2]
```

You'll need to quote names that contain spaces:

```
genius.py "the beatles" "a day in the life"
```

Otherwise there's no way to tell where the artist ends and the song begins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sys module;

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

Or you can use more professional module like [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://genius.com/{0}-{1}-lyrics'.format(raw_input('Enter artist name: ').replace(' ', '_'), raw_input('Enter song name: ').replace(' ', '_')))
```

Comment: he wants to be able to enter all the input values on one line, not do it in one line of Python code.